# How dynamically change components in JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a swing frame that changes dynamically.
Here is the current layout( I am working in IntelliJ IDEA)[image: current format]

As you can see there is a main `JPanel` that has a `JSplitPane`. Inside `JSplitPane` one `JTree`(left) and one `JTable`(right) is there.

So When I clicked on a root node of `JTree` I want to replace the `JTable` to an `Editor` and when clicked on a child node, that table will display there.

```
public class SessionWindow {
    private JFrame mFrame;
    private JPanel container;
    private JTree tableTree;
    private JTable tableDetails;
    private JSplitPane jSplitPane;
    private JScrollPane jScrollTree;
    private JScrollPane jScrollTable;

    private JPanel editorPanel;
    private Project mProject;
    private Disposable parent;

    private ClientSocket socket;


    public SessionWindow(Project mProject, Disposable parent, ClientSocket socket) {
        super();
        this.mProject = mProject;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.socket = socket;

        mFrame = new JFrame();

        mFrame.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 500));
        mFrame.setResizable(true);
        mFrame.setTitle("Debug window");
        mFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mFrame.add(container, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mFrame.pack();
        mFrame.setVisible(true);

        jSplitPane.setResizeWeight(.4f);
        populateDatabase();

        tableTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        tableTree.addTreeSelectionListener(e -> {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)
                    tableTree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

            /* if nothing is selected */
            if (node == null) return;

            IBaseModel model = (IBaseModel) node.getUserObject();
            if (model instanceof DTable) {
                showTablePane();
                DTable table = (DTable) model;
                populateTable(table);
            } else if (model instanceof DDatabase) {
                showEditorPane();
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateDatabase() {
        socket.requestDbDetails();
        DataObserver.getInstance().subscribe(listener);
    }

    private void showTablePane() {
        jSplitPane.setRightComponent(null);
        jSplitPane.setRightComponent(jScrollTree);
        jSplitPane.invalidate();
    }

    private void showEditorPane() {
        editorPanel = new JPanel();

        editorPanel.add(createEditor().getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jSplitPane.setRightComponent(null);
        jSplitPane.setRightComponent(editorPanel);
        jSplitPane.invalidate();
    }

    private Editor createEditor() {
       //create an return editor
        return editor;
    }
}
```

Problem is when I replace the table with an `editor`, the `editor` comes as the right component (not fully visible, but we can see it there)
But when trying to replace `editor` to `table` nothing is coming.

Comment: I suggest that instead of setting the component in the JSplitPane you use one panel with [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) that contains the two components you want to swap.

Comment: @MatheM I didn't get that point

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So start with something simple. Create a JFrame with a JSplitPane and add two components to the split panel (say a button and a label). Add the splitpane to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START of the frame. They create two button and add them to the LINE_START and LINE_END of the frame. Then when you click the buttons you change the component in the right of the split pane. The point is to get this simple code working first. If you have problems you  post that code in the forum. If you works, then you fix your real application.

Comment: @Godwin It is just a suggestion. CardLayout is Layout manager that holds several components (JPanels for simplicity) and you can set which component should be showing. So you would create one panel for editor and one panel for table add both panels to a panel with CardLayout and then set this card layout panel as the right component. Then on some event you would "tell" the card layout panel to show apropriate "card".

Comment: @MatheM Yeh I  have done and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. I simply remove the old child and add the new one remembering the divider location and resetting it. I don't know whether the revalidate/repaint is necessary but I added it for good measure.

```
 /**
   * replace a child of a splitPane with another
   * @param oldChild
   * @param newChild
   */
  public void replaceSplitPaneChild(JComponent oldChild, JComponent newChild) {
    JSplitPane parent = (JSplitPane) oldChild.getParent();
    int dividerLocation = parent.getDividerLocation();
    parent.remove(oldChild);
    parent.add(newChild);
    parent.setDividerLocation(dividerLocation);
    newChild.revalidate();
    newChild.repaint();
  }
```